# Creating a parabolic-shaped arch more automatically

Tags: modeling, modifiers, geometry-nodes, topology, proportional-editing

I'm trying to create an arch in the shape of a parabola, like the arch in [JK Bridge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Juscelino_Kubitschek_bridge) (Brasília-Brazil).

I managed to "model" it manually, using some reference images, but it didn't turn out perfect.

Its base is a trapezoid, and its middle is an inverted trapezoid (but that's just a detail).

[image]

[image]

Is there a way to use modifiers or even Geometry Nodes to make the topology cleaner and more correct?

I've tried using *Proportional Editing*, and while it creates a good parabola (inverse square), the base isn't aligned with the ground.

[image]

Other methods like *Simple Deform* and *Edge Bridge* didn't give me the parabolic effect I'm looking for.

Is there a more automatic way to achieve this?

PS: I'm sending a file to perhaps make it clearer.
The mesh "arc model" would be the example I made manually (and uneven).

[image]

Comment: Hello maybe show some pictures of what you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 2):

Here is the simplest example that I can imagine. This setup use X coordinate of grid, set it to power of 2 and moves Z coordinate at this number.

[image]

Rotate and scale it and it should be good.

Comment: That's just a flat strip, how is this an answer to what he's trying to achieve?

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann there was no such clarification when I wrote this answer.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a more "artistic" solution:

[image]

You could of course also solve this purely mathematically, but in this case it seemed more flexible and easier for me to realize it with a simple construction.

Here, I first create two curves that give the basic shape for the upper and lower shapes. I convert these into a mesh with `Curve to Mesh` and define a corresponding radius beforehand with `Set Curve Radius` to create the changing trapezoidal shape.

I then extrude the lower mesh and move its extruded points to the positions of the upper mesh, merge the shapes and mark the edges as *Sharp Edges*.

[image]
<sub>*(Blender 4.0+)*</sub>